# Arduino high voltage analog out

Tags: arduino, analog, automotive

I am looking for the best way to provide an analog output from an Arduino to control the blend and mode doors in my truck's HVAC system.

They both take a straight "12V" signal from the control unit ("12V" because it is more like 12-14V depending on whether or not the truck is running.)

The control unit uses a simple 10k potentiometer for each of these, as a voltage divider, thus giving a variable voltage between 0 and "12V". The wiper of the blend door potentiometer goes through an 82k resistor, and the wiper of the mode door potentiometer goes through a 3k resistor (I'm not sure if that matters, but if possible, I'd like to match this setup.)

Things I have looked at:

- PWM using MOSFETs - These would have to be high side switches, and I admit I am not skilled enough to be able to pick out components for this. If there is a turnkey high side switching solution that will allow me to use PWM through an RC filter, that would be great. I think this would be the simplest answer, and use the cheapest components.
- Digital potentiometers - again, there is a wealth of these out there, all with different specs, most of which don't seem to support more than 5V. I think potentially this one might work: [MCP41HV31-103E/ST-ND](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005207B.pdf)

So my question is:

I have an Arduino Nano, and I need it to output an analog signal between GND and a reference voltage (in this case 12V to 14V), what is the best way of doing that?

Edit: Additional information, I have found schematics for both the actuator, as well as the control interface:

[Actuator information](https://web.archive.org/web/20131004160413/https://www.silveradosierra.com/how-to-articles/how-to-fix-mode-blend-door-actuator-problems-t67473.html)

[Controls information](https://web.archive.org/web/20180620090937/http://www.silveradosierra.com/how-to-articles/how-to-repair-gmc-ck-series-trucks-hvac-control-unit-t77522.html)

Comment: You can PWM into an RC filter with an N-FET as a low side switch. The viability of that depends on how much current your load will draw.

Comment: PWM output, filtering, op-amp circuit to increase voltage?

Comment: as far as I know this cannot be a low side switch, how would something like that be configured? I have not tested the current draw (I certainly can, just havent yet) but I expect it to be small.

Comment: would something like this circuit work? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/169287/how-to-interface-this-circuit-with-a-0-10v-theatrical-lighting-dimmer

Comment: @Patrick why should it not be a low-side switch? You describe the need for an output voltage, and that can be done low-side switched, high-side switched, or optimally, pushed-pulled.

Comment: try to locate a schematic diagram of the HVAC system .... before you go any further, verify that the positioning is voltage dependent ... you could disconnect the pot wiper and apply a voltage to the wire using an AA cell for 1.5 V ... put several cells in series to make a higher voltage battery

Comment: Ahh, I knew I forgot something, here is a schematic that someone put together in order to help others repair this part: https://web.archive.org/web/20170621163201im_/http://www.silveradosierra.com/gallery/image.php?album_id=13794&image_id=63658

it is on this page: https://web.archive.org/web/20180620090937/http://www.silveradosierra.com/how-to-articles/how-to-repair-gmc-ck-series-trucks-hvac-control-unit-t77522.html that describes the electrical characteristics of the circuits.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have no doubt you are correct, I just don't actually know how to set that up. All I see is a wire that needs 0-12v, I don't have the ground wire from the actuator to splice into in order to do low side switching.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Ohh, are you saying I can switch the ground of the RC circuit using a mosfet? I could see that working. That would be much simpler than anything I came up with.

Comment: @Patrick no, I wasn't saying that. But you saying you have no ground reference makes no sense either: you'll need a reference potential any way.

Comment: Well then I'm confused. Yes I obviously have a ground, but its the ground for the entire truck, I have no way of putting something between the actuator and ground, without ripping apart half of my dashboard.

Comment: If filtered PWM won't work plenty of classic current mode DACs are meant to be used with an op-amp in a way that can readily give a 12 volt output range.  The series resistor makes it seem you need a signal not to be a power supply, but automotive electrical environments are notoriously nasty.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I again confess to my beginner-ness. I know what a DAC is, and I know what an Op-Amp is, but I unfortunately have no idea where to start in choosing devices for this kind of thing. Could you provide some reading, or point me in a direction as to what devices/device families to look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jack Creasey definitely has a point, you don't know much about the input you are trying to drive. However, I think it is a safe bet to say the actuators are not current-driven; their input seems to have a 100 kOhm resistor in series, which would result in minimal currents and low reliability for current-controlled inputs.
That being said, two other approaches could very well be worth a try. Both were briefly discussed in the comments before:

### MOSFET as low side switch, RC-Filter

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWbW05.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The input marked with "Arduino PWM" can be birectly connected to any Arduino pin with PWM capabilities. The output ("to climate control") should either replace the middle pin of the potentiometer, or, if you are sure that the input is voltage-controlled, directly to the control input your actuators.

The left part of the shown circuit amplifies (and inverts) the [PWM](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Foundations/PWM) signal from your Arduino to 12V.
Thr right part is a simple RC low pass filter, which turns the fast-switching PWM signal into a mostly stable voltage. Basically, the part of the signal which consists of higher frequencies is rejected and only the low frequency is allowed to pass (therefore "low pass filter"). To learn more about how this works and how to calculate it exactly, have a look at [this](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/low-pass-filter-tutorial-basics-passive-RC-filter/) or any other tutorial.

The circuit is not perfect, though. If the output is loaded (e.g. by the climate control), the output voltage might drop significantly. However, this should not be the case due to small input current of your actuator's control input.
Also, the two stages are not buffered, meaning the low pass filter will slightly load the left circuit part (therefore the resistor choice: R3 (10 kOhm) should be much larger than R2 (1 kOhm) to make the effect imperceptible).
As noted in the comments, a n-channel MOSFET should be used instead of a BJT, because the BJT will always have a Vce(sat) of around half a volt (which limits the minimal output voltage). The suggested IRLZ34n has a Rds(on) of 35 mOhm, which results in a minimal output voltage of practically zero.

### RC-Filter, Non-inverting amplifier

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDrfUo.png)</sup>

The external wiring of the second circuit is identical to the first one.

Even the idea behind the circuit is similar: here the PWM signal is transformed into an analog voltage first, then amplified. Since amplifying analog voltages with transistors only is quite tricky, we use an operational amplifier (op-amp) instead. The circuit is known as "non-inverting amplifier", since the output voltage follows the equation [image]. Again, there are tons of tutorials available online, [here's](https://www.electronicshub.org/non-inverting-operational-amplifiers/) the first one I found.
The op-amp should be a rail-to-rail type (meaning the output voltage swing includes both the negative and positive supply rail, GND and 12V in this case) and needs to be suited for supply voltages of at least 12V, the more headroom the better.

This circuit overcomes the problems noted for the first one (the two stages are buffered and the output is low-impedance) at the cost of higher complexity.
If you need voltages higher than 12V, you can of course adjust the gain by choosing other resistors. For example, you can trim the circuit to output up to 14V, but keep in mind that in that case if the supply is only 12V, the output will clip and you will reach the maximum output voltage (12V) at ~4.3V input.

---

I'm quite confident that you can manage to solve your problem with the knowledge about the circuits shown above, especially if what you wrote in your comment to Jack Cearsey's answer holds true. In that case, you should connect the output of the shown circuits directly to the control input of the actuators.

Please let us know which solution worked for you, and which one didn't (and why), so that others can benefit from it as well.

Comment: Neither of these seem like good solutions. The first can never get to 0V because of VCE(sat) and the second won't work over the full range because the inputs are NOT rail to rail....only the outputs.

Comment: I agree that the first circuit is a "quick and dirty" solution, probably using a logic level n-MOSFET (e.g. IRLZ34n) would improve it a bit.
However, I fail to see the problem you hinted at for the second one. Is there some number in the datasheet I missed? I even tried it in simulation (with the exact same opamp) and the results are alright - applying PWM signals gives me the full desired output range.

Comment: I think I see the problem with the first solution, is it that even when Q1 is fully on, it will still have some resistance, and that allows some flow through R3? I also cannot see the problem with #2, if the lm6132 is a rail to rail op-amp, what is meant by "the inputs are not rail to rail"?

Comment: @Patrick looking at the datasheet (https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm6134.pdf?ts=1602081019111&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F), figure 8 shows the input characteristics. While it's shown at +/-5V you can clearly see that the inputs stop working at about 4V. Look at figure 30 to understand why. The LM6134 is almost rail to rail output, but definitely not rail-rail input. Most models miss these characteristics.

Comment: That, however, should not pose a problem, because the input voltage will never exceed 5V, while the supply voltage is 12V. There is plenty of headroom here. meanwhile, the very same figure shows that the negative supply rail (GND here) is included in the input voltage range, as it is necessary for this application.

Comment: as an update, I've ordered parts for both of these to test them (fortunately these are relatively cheap parts), I'll report back with information and results. If neither of these works I'll try the more expensive, but likely more turnkey solution from @JackCreasey next.

Comment: I got the op amp circuit together and it looks pretty promising, looks like I can get pretty much my whole 12v rail range. Going to do a more complete proof of concept and actually hook it up in the truck, but this is promising!

Comment: @JackCreasey one thing I'm having trouble with understanding, you mention figure 8 when you say the inputs are not rail to rail, but it looks to me like figure 8 depends on Vs being 5v, figure 7 is the same graph for 2.5v and it seems like the bias current goes positive at Vs-1 volt for both. What is Vs here? If its the supply voltage, does that mean that my input, which will never go above 5v will be fine because my supply is 12v?

Comment: @Patrick The Vs rail is shown as 5V ....but you will be using 12V. The thing to note from the diagram is that the inputs stop being effective at about 1V less than whatever Vs is set to.

Comment: Excellent, so my intuition was correct. Unfortunately I've realized something about the opamp circuit, it has a fixed gain, and thus will not scale the output based on changes to the 12v rail. That would probably still work but it could cause some changes to the position of the servo when the rail voltage changes. I will test the simpler transistor circuit next.

Comment: Got the transistor (well, actually bought the recommended mosfet) circuit together, and honestly theres not a lot of difference in the output. It seems to work about equally well, and since it is just switching the 12v rail, and its not loaded (just goes into a couple of op amps in the servo) it should work reasonably well. @K.Krull, you mentioned other shortcomings of this circuit, could you elaborate?

Comment: I should say, since its just switching the 12v rail, it wont have the scaling problem of the opamp circuit.

Comment: I updated the answer considering the comments and added the information you asked for. It is a very minor problem in my opinion, though.

Comment: I appreciate it, and that all makes sense. I should be able to test the prototype either tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: Just tested it, the circuit with the mosfet works pretty well! I'm marking this as the answer, but I believe any of the circuits in these answers would work.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you don't know much about the input port used for your feature.
Is it a reference voltage or a reference current being used to set the operating point?
Trying to use a PWM may not work, and I'd suggest is unlikely to work, and too difficult to program if you are new to it.

Given that you 'know that the potentiometer used is a 10k (linear one assumes), then the best solution is to use an I2C digital potentiometer.
They are many available and the [DS3502](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS3502.pdf) may be a worthwhile choice.
You can get this as a low cost easily wired PCB such as [here](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/737/ds3502-i2c-potentiometer-1634080.pdf), which also has Arduino code shown in the example.

[image]

This DS3502 *IS NOT* suitable for direct connection to the 12V rail in your car (even with a 17v Absolute max rating). The 12V can easily have spikes in excess of 17-19V and could easily kill the device.

You should ensure that you include some form of supply limiting.
Since the maximum current is just a few uA I'd suggest a series 100 Ohm resistor and a TL431 shunt regulator. Study this datasheet to understand the [TL431](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf?ts=1602025394963&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTL431).
The shunt circuit is simple and you only need one regulator for both (or more) potentiometers you replace.

[image]

Set the shunt regulated to about 15V, which is above the maximum likely from the battery (13.8V) when not charging. This prevents the regulator sinking current on a fully charged battery and it will only conduct when the voltage is above 15V.

Comment: I appreciate the very well explained answer, and the part suggestions and cautions. I do have a question though, you mention that the systems might work based on current, how would I test this? Also, pwm is trivial to implement on an arduino, and I'm a professional software developer, could you explain how that could be too difficult?

Comment: I was just doing some more digging, and found a schematic of the actuator: https://web.archive.org/web/20131004160413/https://www.silveradosierra.com/how-to-articles/how-to-fix-mode-blend-door-actuator-problems-t67473.html the two are apparently identical parts, and are voltage controlled.

Comment: @patrick PWM is easy to set ....generating a voltage over a large range (0-12 or 0-some variable upper supply) is more of a challenge. 
As shown in the other answer posted recently, there may be other solution ....but neither of those will work over a large range.

Answer (score -6):

Use a buck boost converter that takes 5V as input and gives 0-12V, use that output to give feedback to microcontroller for voltage sensing and drive converters En(enable) pin using microcontroller.

Microcontroller will switch En pin on/off depending upon feedback voltage and required output voltage.

Comment: PWM'ing the EN pin of a boost converter sounds like a pretty bad solution, especially for a beginner (all sorts of problems can arise and he will have a hard time diagnosing them). Especially considering that he already has a 12V source...

Comment: Have you use UC3845, Please read the datasheet, we use its Comp pin, in the same way, I suggested to regulate the voltage.

Comment: a comp (==comparator) input pin is **absolutely not the same** as an enable pin.

Comment: use uc3845 comp pin then